# How can set integer in column as text instead of #####?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

The value in column E is shown as below , all integer with `Scientific way`:

[image: the initial format]

I want to format it as text,all integer number shown as text format:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E:E")
    .NumberFormat = "Text"
End With
```

[image: integer shown with ####]

All the cells in column E are full with `###`,how can make the integer number in text format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it is not enough to change the format, you also need to explicitly convert the numeric values in the cells into text strings. For example, like this:

```
Sub convertNumbersToText()
Dim oCell As Range, nonEmptyCells As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set nonEmptyCells = Application.Intersect(.UsedRange, _
            .Range("E:E")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        For Each oCell In nonEmptyCells.Cells
            oCell.Value2 = "'" & Format(oCell.Value, "0")
        Next oCell
        .Range("E:E").NumberFormat = "@"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe it is no need to code complicatedly.Simple is better than complex.

Comment: @newview Not always. *The more the programmer thinks, the less the users and the computer work.* Iterating over every cell in a column means iterating over a million cells. UsedRange is usually much smaller. Hence Intersect will give a much shorter column. If not all cells are filled there, then SpecialCells will select only them.

Answer (score 0):

With the simplest code:

```
Sub SetCellFormat()
    For Each oCell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E:E")
        oCell.Value = "'" & Format(oCell.Value, "0")
        oCell.NumberFormat = "@"
    Next oCell
End Sub
```

Or combine the two lines with a long line

```
    oCell.Value = "'" & Format(oCell.Value, "0")
    oCell.NumberFormat = "@"
```

The most shortest vba code to format cells in column E:

```
Sub SetCellFormat()
    For Each oCell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E:E")
        oCell.Value = Format("'" & Format(oCell.Value, "0"), "@")
    Next oCell
End Sub
```